# How can I open files in the Coda editor file browser using the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, coda

I am using coda as my main editor on mac. But I want to use just the keyboard for navigating through file browser. This I was able to quite easily by installing the plugin to [switch between editor and file browser](http://habitatus.net/blog/2009/08/switch-focus-coda-plugin/) and then turning off the feature which opens files on a single-click or when it is focussed.

Now my problem is how to open a file in editor when I press enter - the file rename mode gets activated when I press enter while navigating in file browser. any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried pressing command o instead of enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both <kbd>return</kbd> and <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> work to open files in my version of coda.

Is your <kbd>enter</kbd> key only an enter key or combined?

It doesn't look like that plug in changes key bindings so you might have to search elsewhere for something that is altering the standard behavior. Other tweaks or software possibly?

Comment: pressing `return` renames the file and pressing `command + o` opens the Open file dialog. Are you saying that `command + o` opens a file in editor in coda?

Comment: even removing the plugin doesn't work.

Comment: I would have been surprised if that plug in was causing the issue. It works for me return or command+o - so either I don't really understand what you mean "open in editor" or you have something else broken that eludes me. Have you contacted Panic - their support is top notch and perhaps they can understand better what you mean or suggest another plug in to better meet your needs.

Comment: turns out that I have to press `command + down` to open the file.

Comment: NICE!? Thánk you! This had been driving me nuts. thank you so much for finding the answer to your own question :p (And sharing it of course!)

Comment: @ShiVik Good catch! This had been bugging me as well. Please consider posting `command + down` as a separate answer and accepting it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> to open a file you have selected.